# Best Way to Layout TimeSeries Data in Spark DataFrame - Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, time-series, apache-spark-sql

I am importing data from the Federal Reserve Economic Dataset API. Each request returns a daily, weekly, monthly, or yearly time series. My end goal is to do variable selection and build a bayesian based model that uses the selected time series as predictors for a specific time series. What is the best way to structure this data into a data frame?

According to this [documentation](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/spark-ts-a-new-library-for-analyzing-time-series-data-with-apache-spark/) I would think my data should laid out in the "Instants" [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Z3Z.png). However my attempts toward that end all end up prohibitively slow after trying to join what amounts to over 200,000 columns. The other format from the documentation reference below is the "TimeSeriesRDD", but the time series being imported often have no date overlap and range from 1930 to present. So, what is the best way to structure this data into a data frame?

An example of how to load data from FRED into your recommended format would be great appreciated!

Here is my first approach that is prohibitively slow

```
for (seriesId <- allSeries) {
    val series = loadSeriesFromAPI(seriesId, spark)
    allSeries = allSeries.join(series, allSeries.col("date") === series.col(seriesId + "_date"), "outer")
    allSeries = allSeries.drop(seriesId + "_date")
}
```

And my second that I would have to load in data 1 column and 1 row at a time

```
for(row <- series) {
  val insertStr = "%s, %g".
    format(
      row.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Date]]("date").asInstanceOf[String],
      parseDoubleOrZero(row.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Double]]("value").asInstanceOf[String])
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a DataFrame with 200.000 columns is not a good idea. One thing that I would recommend is to split the problem a bit without mixing too much the technologies:

1. Data ingestion: How big your series actually are? Avoid joins as much as possible (joins imply shuffling, shuffling implies network and this will make everything slow). I would collect the data with Scala and keep it in memory if it fits, if not, I would still collect batches of series in Scala and convert each batch in a Spark DataFrame.
2. Dataframe creation: If you manage to get your data in memory then you could try the following snippet that will create you a DataFrame:

```scala
case class Point(timestamp: Long, value: Long)
case class Series(id: String, points: List[Point])

val s1 = Series("s1", List(Point(1, 100), Point(2, 200), Point(3, 100)))
val s2 = Series("s2", List(Point(1, 1000), Point(3, 100)))

val seriesDF = sc.parallelize(Array(s1, s2)).toDF
seriesDF.show()

seriesDF.select($"id", explode($"points").as("point"))
    .select($"id", $"point.timestamp", $"point.value")
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|              points|
+---+--------------------+
| s1|[[1,100], [2,200]...|
| s2| [[1,1000], [3,100]]|
+---+--------------------+
+---+---------+-----+
| id|timestamp|value|
+---+---------+-----+
| s1|        1|  100|
| s1|        2|  200|
| s1|        3|  100|
| s2|        1| 1000|
| s2|        3|  100|
+---+---------+-----+
```

For a more fancy way to handle time series I would recommend the following project: https://github.com/twosigma/flint

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I like where you are going and have a couple questions. First, lets say I wanted to use a random forest based algorithm to narrow down the number of columns. How could I do that without ingesting all the data into a data frame? Second, is it normal to store a large amount of data in batches, it seems like querying data would be much harder that way?